# Right way to use REST API in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, promise, frontend

I am using a free account on [weatherstack.com](https://weatherstack.com/) to get weather info on a specified city. The relevant component from the App is the following

```js
const WeatherInfo = (props) => {
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState()
  const url = 'http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key='
  + process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY + '&query=' + props.city

  axios.get(url)
       .then(response => {setWeather(response.data)})

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Weather in {props.city}</p>
      <p><b>Temperature:</b> {weather.current.temperature} celsius</p>
      <img src={weather.current.weather_icons[0]} alt="Country flag" width="150"></img>
      <p><b>Wind:</b> {weather.current.wind_speed} mph direction {weather.current.wind_dir}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This fails with `TypeError: weather.current is undefined` because I believe the `axios.get` is asyncronously called so the return happens before the `setWeather()` call inside the `.then()`. So I replaced the return statement with the following:

```js
  if (weather === undefined) {
    return (
      <div>Loading...</div>
    )
  }
  else {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Weather in {props.city}</p>
        <p><b>Temperature:</b> {weather.current.temperature} celsius</p>
        <img src={weather.current.weather_icons[0]} alt="Country flag" width="150"></img>
        <p><b>Wind:</b> {weather.current.wind_speed} mph direction {weather.current.wind_dir}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

This succeeds briefly and then fails with the same error as previous. I guess I must have some fundamental misunderstanding of the correct way to wait for a response before rendering.

> **Question**
> What is the correct way to wait for REST call when using react?

Comment: This is covered in [the React hooks FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-do-data-fetching-with-hooks), but TL;DR put your axios call in a `useEffect` hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you set state, your functional component will re-render, causing the body of the function to execute again. This means that when your axios call does eventually complete, doing `setWeather(response.data)` will cause your functional component body to run again, making you do another get request.

Since you only want to run your axios get request once, you can put your axios get request inside of the `useEffect()` hook. This will allow you to only run your get request when the component initially mounts:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
...

const WeatherInfo = (props) => {
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const url = 'http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=' + process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY + '&query=' + props.city
    
    const cancelTokenSource = axios.CancelToken.source();
    axios.get(url, {cancelToken: cancelTokenSource.token})
       .then(response => {setWeather(response.data)});

    return () => cancelTokenSource.cancel();
  }, [props.city, setWeather]);


  return weather ? (
    <div>
      <p>Weather in {props.city}</p>
      <p><b>Temperature:</b> {weather.current.temperature} celsius</p>
      <img src={weather.current.weather_icons[0]} alt="Country flag" width="150"></img>
      <p><b>Wind:</b> {weather.current.wind_speed} mph direction {weather.current.wind_dir}</p>
    </div>
  ) : <div>Loading...</div>;
}
```

The above `useEffect()` callback will only run when the things in the dependency array (second argument of useEffect) change. Since `setWeather` is a function and doesn't change, and `props.city` only changed when the prop is changed, the callback is only executed when your component initially mounts (provided the `city` prop isn't changing). The `useEffect()` hook also allows you to return a "clean-up" function, which, in this case, will get called when your component unmounts. Here I have used Axios's `CancelToken` to generate a source token so that you can cancel any outgoing requests if your component unmounts during the request.

Comment: I've left out the token business because the course I'm following hasn't covered that yet, but this all appears to work fine. At least if I generate more than 1 `WeatherInfo` component in the App then the first one works fine but the second fails with the old error but this looks like a problem with (weatherstack.com) API since it claims I've made the request using https which is not allowed on a free account even though it is clearly making a http request.

Answer (score 1):

First of all wrap `axios` in useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get(url)
       .then(response => {setWeather(response.data)})
});
```

then wrap return part with `weather` in condition:

```
return ( 
      <div>
        <p>Weather in {props.city}</p>
        {
            weather && (
              <>
                <p><b>Temperature:</b> {weather.current.temperature} celsius</p>
                <img src={weather.current.weather_icons[0]} alt="Country flag" width="150"></img>
                <p><b>Wind:</b> {weather.current.wind_speed} mph direction {weather.current.wind_dir}</p>
              </>
            )
        }   
      </div>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will continuously make the axios call on every rerender. You need to put that call into a function and call if once on Component load. Also your render function should check to see if the state is set. Here is a basic example and a Sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-glitter-1ci2j?file=/src/App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const axioscall = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({ city: "Scottsdale", tempt: 75 });
    }, 1000);
  });
};

export default (props) => {
  const [weather, setWeather] = React.useState(null);


  React.useEffect(() => {
    axioscall()
      .then((result) => setWeather(result));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {weather ? (
        <>
          <p>Weather in {weather.city}</p>
          <p>
            <b>Temperature:</b> {weather.temp} F
          </p>
        </>
      ) : (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```